# How can I position a DIV relative to another DIV that is not it's parent

Tags: html, css

I need to make a `div` relative to another (act as a child) `div` that is not its parent. Unfortunately I cannot use `position:absolute` on the second `div` to force it into the first one, because when the window is made smaller the `div` is then out of place.

This is what I need to happen:

```
<div id="first" style="position:relative;" >
    <div id="second" style="position:absolute;"></div>
 </div>
```

This is what I currently have:

```
<div id="first" ></div>
<!--there is other content/html between the divs-->
<div id="second"></div>
```

Is there any way to make the second `div` relative to the first `div`? Without changing the HTML code of the page.

More info: There is a piece of content outputted to the webpage. I need to reposition this piece of content once it has been output using CSS/JQuery. So I need to make that piece of content relative to content that is already on the screen. It cannot be a child of the first div and using `position:absolute` wont do. The two `div` are not beside each other, and are at completely different ends of the page.

I basically need the second div to act as a child of the first div, without it actually being its child.

Comment: Not using pure CSS. You'll have to use JavaScript / jQuery

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Can you use transform (translateX and translateY) css3 property? or use just margins with negative values.

Comment: Simply post your http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com

Comment: I need the first ``div`` to act as a parent of the second ``div``.  So I can set the second div as ``position:absolute`` and it will remain in the first ``div`` which will be ``position:relative``. Except, the actual HTML of the ``divs`` are not parent/child. They are set like the above. ``<div id="first" ></div>
<div id="second"></div>``

Answer (score 0):

using javascript (for example):

```
var div1 = document.getElementById('first');
var div2 = document.getElementById('second');

div1.style.marginTop = div2.offsetTop; //set the margin top of the first div = the margin top of the second div
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know width and height of the `#first` element, then you can do the following:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
.parent{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}

#first{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

#second{
    min-width: 20px;
    min-height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: -200px; /* equal to #first height */
    max-width: 200px; /* equal to #first width */
    max-height: 200px; /* equal to #first height */
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/W74bb/)**

Answer (score -1):

Here is [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ucapac/1/edit)

```
<div id="first" style='float:left;'></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```